# Power BI Power Query: Adding Custom Column is Changing Date Format

Tags: datetime, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have an Azure Databricks data source, and I am experiencing the strangest behavior I have ever seen. I have a datetime field that has milliseconds that I need to retain.

[image]

I am able to parse this out to get just the milliseconds, or create a text-friendly key field, but as soon as I add any Custom Column step, the date gets reformatted and drops the milliseconds, which then ruins my other calculations.

[image]

The datetime column remains Text data type.  The custom column is not referencing my datetime--it's a completely unrelated calculation.  It's as if, during calculation of a new field, it creates a shallow copy that then re-detects the metadata and tries to be smart about datetimes.

I have no idea how to stop this.  I have disabled the following Options:

[image]

This is literally blocking me from doing duration analysis on events.  Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Can you show the code for your custom column?

Comment: @mkRabbani so the custom column has nothing to do with the datetime field, which is why it's so strange. For example, I am calculating a flag based on if another column = "created account", then 1 else 0.  As soon as I add this step in the M code, the datetime field changes back to standard "MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS XM" and I can't pull out the milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this below code for generating the custom column, you will see the values in custom column is up to Second. But internally the millisecond also available with that value. You can do your further sorting or duration calculation which should consider the millisecond as well.

```
DateTime.FromText([Timestamp])
```

[image]